# Use external XTemplate in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: file, external, sencha-touch-2

I need to use an external file with content from an XTemplate.

Basically, I want to use the an external file with no "strange" solution, like use "XTemplate.from", or put the XTemplate objects in variables. Something like this:

list.html

```
<div>Name: #{object.name} </div>
```

file.js

```
...
content = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    scroll: 'vertical',
    data : planetEarth,
    tpl: "index.html"
});
...
```

Basically, once I define a file for the tpl, this should be compiled automatically.

Any idea? Thanks!